# Can incompatible atlases generate a common differential structure

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

A textbook in tensor calculus written by a one of my professors is full of statements that seem to skip important details, so I'm usually skeptical about certain claims that I find in his book but not in other books on differential geometry (the author is a physicist, not a mathematician).

One statement in particular is a real head-scratcher for me. Following the example very similar to this one:
[Manifold with different differential structure but diffeomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218141/manifold-with-different-differential-structure-but-diffeomorphi), the textbook states:

*Even though the two different atlases are incompatible they produce **compatible** differential structures. That means that incompatible atlases can produce equivalent differential structures.*

From the answers to the linked question I know now that these two differential structures are indeed equivalent in the sense that there is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ diffeomorphism between them, but I still belive those differential structures are in fact **incompatible**, because by taking a union of the two maximal atlases we still have two charts from the provided example that have a non-differentiable change of coordinates map.

Am I right in finding writing in this textbook really sloppy or is it that I just still don't understand something about compatibility of atlases?

Comment: Well, if by "compatible atlases" the author means "their union is an atlas" while by "compatible differential structures" the author means "the differential structures are isomorphic" (that is, the resulting manifolds are diffeomorphic) then the sentence makes sense. Arguably, this is not a very good choice of terminology.